# how to remove subscription callbacks in redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have a subscriber redis client instance that is performing a callback when entries in the db expire..  I tried adding an initial unsubscribe call to remove previous any existing listeners, but it does not seem to be working:

```
const setOnExpire = (onExpire) => {
  client.config('set', 'notify-keyspace-events', 'Ex', () => {
     subscriber.unsubscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired', 0); // <-- this does not seem to be doing what I was hoping it would...
     subscriber.subscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired', () => {
      subscriber.on('message', function (channel, key) {
        onExpire(key);
      });
    });
  });
};

setOnExpire(() => { console.log('foo'); });
setOnExpire(() => { console.log('bar'); }); // my intention is to replace the callback that logs "foo"
client.hmsetAsync(someKey, someAttrs).then(() => {
  client.expireAsync(someKey, 5);
});
```

I run this, hoping to only see "bar" get logged when the record expires in 5 seconds, however instead, I see "foo" and "bar."

How can I properly remove the pre-existing subscriber.on('message') listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. I think this is not a Redis related problem, it's just an application-level problem. You only need to call `subscriber.subscribe` once to set up a subscription. You want to support only one callback, so store that callback internally. And every time `setOnExpire` get called, just replace the callback with a new one. I'm not a JavaScript expert, bellow code snippet works fine on my computer:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);

var client = redis.createClient();
var subscriber = redis.createClient();

const setOnExpire = function() {
    var notify_on = false;
    var promise;
    var callback = function(key) { };
    return (onExpire) => {
        if (notify_on) {
            promise.then(()=> {
                callback = onExpire;
            });
        } else {
            promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                notify_on = true;
                client.config('set', 'notify-keyspace-events', 'Ex', () => {
                    resolve();
                });
            });

            promise.then(() => {
                subscriber.subscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired', () => {
                    subscriber.on('message', function (channel, key) {
                        callback(key);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };
}();


setOnExpire(() => { console.log('foo'); });
setOnExpire(() => { console.log('bar'); }); // my intention is to replace the callback that logs "foo"

client.hmsetAsync('hello', 'yesl', 'thankyou').then(() => {
  client.expireAsync('hello', 5);
});
```